# Re-factoring with switch

Tags: javascript

So, i have the following jQuery code which targets some DOM elements,i want to change the code into a switch statment but i cannot find a way to do it,anyone has any ideeas or can give me a model to do it?

```
if ($('.similar-products')) {                                       
    $('.similarproducts').append(iframe_html);
} 

if ($('.partial--product')){
    $('.partial--product').append(iframe_html);
}

if ($('.product-page')){
    $('div.product-page').append(iframe_html);
}

if($('#section-product-page')){
   $('#section-product-page').append(iframe_html);
}
//needs fix
if($('.swatch-product-id-*')){
   $('.swatch-product-id-*').append(iframe_html);
}

if($('.product__tabs')){
   $('.product__tabs').append(iframe_html);
}
if($('.main-content-wrapper')){
   $('.main-content-wrapper').append(iframe_html);
}

if($('#shopify-section-product-description-bottom-template')){
   $('#shopify-section-product-description-bottom-template').append(iframe_html);
}
if($('.product-details-inline')){
   $('.product-details-inline').append(iframe_html);
}

if($('.social-footer')){
   $('.social-footer').prepend(iframe_html);
}
if($('.section-related-products')){
   $('.section-related-products').append(iframe_html);
}

if($('.product-details')){
   $('.product-details').append(iframe_html);
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to change it to a switch statement? Also, you do realise your `if` statements will *always* be truthy as jQuery returns an object from the selector?

Comment: I want to change them to a switch statment for a faster optimization,someone suggested it and i liked the ideea but i don't see how i can do that or if it will even work,i just want to re-factor the code

Comment: A `switch` does have nothing to do with your control flow. Don't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might be easier.

```
var elements = [
    '.similar-products',
    '.partial--product',
    '.product-page',
    '#section-product-page',
    '.swatch-product-id-*',
    '.product__tabs',
    '.main-content-wrapper',
    '#shopify-section-product-description-bottom-template',
    '.product-details-inline',
    '.social-footer'
];

elements.forEach(element => {
    if($(element)){
        $(element).append(iframe_html);
    }
});
```

From what I could tell you're doing the same thing in each `if` statement. Creating an array of strings with your jquery selectors and run the same function on them. Switch statement 'might' be better than a load of `if` statements, but this way makes it easier, to add or remove the check and append.

Answer (score 0):

it would be even easier than a switch in this case a loop iterating over an array:

```
let selectors = [
    '.similar-products',
    '.partial--product',
    ... ]


selectors.forEach(x => {
    if($(x).length > 0) {
        $(x).append(iframe_html)
    } 
})
```